# using two domain same database with different wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I want to use, same database, (content / users / comments / meta's / categories etc.) for another wordpress install in my sub directory.

I actually want to create mobile version of my site. But i dont want to use, any mobile detect script ory css3 media queries. Just want to create my new theme (for mobile version)

**For example;**

the main domain has also sub domain like ;

```
maindomain.com // root
mobile.maindomain.com // sub directory
```

How this could be possible ?

Comment: If you want to have a different domain and different directory for mobile site but want to pinch content from same database then the fundamentals and url resolution will break within one wordpress for example post url for mobile site might take your users to maindomain post url as this would be picked up from database settings table which is shared between both. Most people achieve this by having a mobile theme which you can switch to on mobile device with different header and content even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the nice things about WordPress is the great number of hooks in the code allowing you to extend or override core functionality.

One way to approach this problem would be to set an Apache environment variable in your vhost file for each site that could be used in the WordPress bootstrap process to over-ride the theme and base URL setup.

e.g. in Apache vhost add:

```
SetEnv WP_CONTEXT main
```

and

```
SetEnv WP_CONTEXT mobile
```

(or equivalent if you're using a different webserver).

In wp-config.php:

```
switch ($_SERVER['WP_CONTEXT']) {
    case 'main':
        define('WP_HOME','http://maindomain.com');
        define('WP_SITEURL','http://maindomain.com');
    break;

    case 'mobile':
        define('WP_HOME','http://mobile.maindomain.com');
       define('WP_SITEURL','http://mobile.maindomain.com');
    break;
}
```

This will set the base URLs based on the environment variable.

Then in plugin add the following filters:

```
add_filter('template', 'change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'change_theme');

function change_theme() 
{
    switch ($_SERVER['WP_CONTEXT']) {
        case 'main':
            return 'main';
        break;

        case 'mobile':
           return 'mobile';
        break;
}
```

This needs to be in a plugin so that it's loaded before the normal theme loading process (functions.php is part of the theme and hence too late).  These filters will intercept and over-ride the theme settings from the database.

Comment: Should i manage my apache or server ? Cant i use this hooks with shared hosting ?

Comment: You could use SetEnvIf Request_URI "reg_ex" WP_CONTEXT=main in your .htaccess file where 'reg_ex' is a regular expression matching the domains.

Comment: or add `SetEnvIf HOST "^maindomain.com" WP_CONTEXT=main` to your .htaccess

Comment: I will try this if it work thas gonna make me so happy Roscius

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that directly, as WP stores its url in database.
AFAIK there is a way to "link" tables in sql, so it might be the way - link everything beside wp_options for example, but still it is a tricky way.

Comment: i think something abut wp-db.php ?

Comment: You should then hack into every wpdb query and rewrite url... But than comes more complicated problem. Propabbly You would like to change only requests that corresponds to urls of elements, but not to images sources. And that is something, that might be impossible.

Comment: i found a something on SE but i didint try yet, could be work huh ? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/how-to-create-another-version-of-my-site-based-on-the-same-database

Comment: define('WP_HOME',"http://{XXX}");
define('WP_SITEURL',"http://XXX");
in a wp-config.php is a solution, but might not work correctly.

Comment: You can try, but I have failed with that solution once.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same probleme and it works at least for me:

1. add this code to the functions.php in the mobile theme:

   remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');

read more about this hook from **[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/redirect_canonical/)**

2. add these in the wp-config.php:

   define('WP_HOME','http://mobile.maindomain.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://mobile.maindomain.com');

read more these hooks from **[Here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)**

**Apply these changes in the wordpress installation of the mobile version**