# Duplicate Woocommerce pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been struggling to know what I should do for that case :

I'm building an e-commerce website for a client and we are using Woocommerce for the e-commerce plateform.

We want to separate the website in two sides:

- Corporate : presents the company and the product selled (so it needs access to woocommerce loops etc...)
- Store : contains all the Woocommerce pages (login page, cart page, user's account settings page, products pages etc...)

They also each have their own design (navigation bar is different etc...).

And would each have their own subdomain :

- Corporate : domain.com
- Store : **store**.domain.com

I've thought about Wordpress Multisite but I need all the Woocommerce datas to be **exactly the same** on both site.

Is there a way to have 2 differents products template on Woocommerce (one for the corporate side and another one for the store side)? Same for product archive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the corporate site is only displaying product data, why not use the WooCommerce API to retrieve the product data from the "store.domain.com" site? That way you have a flexible setup.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea ! But then I would set the main site on store.domain.com right ? How could I manage to have pages with urls like http://example.com/about-us if the whole site is on http://store.example.com ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having to 2 installations of wp sharing one Database by configuring it in wp_config.php with conditions to change the theme that match the domain name.
[using two domain same database with different wordpress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381099/using-two-domain-same-database-with-different-wordpress-theme)

BTW if your are considering to run a MUWP site there is a plugin that does this easily allowing you to keep separate themes and update the posts and page to another musite.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-post-duplicator/